# Creating a SQL Server trigger error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am getting an error and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am creating a trigger on a table to archive this table daily. The table is truncated and new data is inserted in the morning every day. I want to archive it once this happens.

This is my code to create the trigger:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('trg_archive_inventory_table') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER trg_archive_inventory_table
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_archive_inventory_table 
ON inventory 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   /* delete data from one year ago */
   DELETE FROM [cadc].[dbo].[inventory_archive] 
   WHERE entry_date = CAST((DATEADD(yy, -1, GetDate())) as DATE);

   /* insert todays inventory */
   INSERT INTO [cadc].[dbo].[inventory_archive] (sku, tag_id , load_id, batch, status, qc_status, location, eaches, units, cartons, r_date, e_date, zone_1, zone_2, loc_type, loc_pick, mod_time, receiver_no, mfg_code, each_unit, unit_carton)
       SELECT 
           sku, tag_id , load_id, batch, status, qc_status, location, eaches, 
           units, cartons, r_date, e_date, zone_1, zone_2, loc_type, loc_pick, 
           mod_time, receiver_no, mfg_code, each_unit, unit_carton 
       FROM 
           [cadc].[dbo].[inventory];
END
```

I keep getting the following error:

> 'CREATE/ALTER TRIGGER' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

I have also tried prefixing the inventory table with `[cadc].[dbo].[inventory]` but I receive the same error.

Googling has help understand the problem.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Just a word of caution: a trigger is fired whenever that operation happens - you have no control over when and how many times it's fired. Therefore, it should be **as lean** as possible and it should *not* do any extensive operations - like archiving. Something like this - *archive this table daily* - sounds much more suitable to a **scheduled SQL Server Agent job** that can be launched *once a day* (or night) to do its task

Comment: Strongly agree with marc_s, don't use a trigger for this.

Comment: This should be an nightly process, schedule a window job for this

Comment: As I said - this should not be a trigger to begin with. But the error message seems pretty clear - you **cannot** use a three-part name for a table - `[cadc].[dbo].[inventory]` - you must restrict yourself to a two-part name (schema + object name) only - `[dbo].[inventory]`

Comment: @marc_s OK I don't have access to set it up as a job with SQL Agent job which is why I used a trigger.  I know for sure that the job to import data to my inventory table runs exactly once a day.  I have a check to see if the table has been archived already so I know it won't be done twice in one day. I understand why I would want to separate the 2 processes and will talk to my DB admin.  Thanks

Comment: @marc_s I tried all every way for the table and it turns out I just needed to set the database above as it was looking at master and not cadc database.  I post my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set the database above the trigger

```
IF OBJECT_ID('trg_archive_inventory_table') IS NOT NULL
DROP TRIGGER trg_archive_inventory_table
GO

USE cadc;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_archive_inventory_table ON  inventory AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @lastrun date;

/* make sure the inventory table was updated this morning*/ 
SELECT @lastrun = MAX(entry_date) FROM [cadc].[dbo].[inventory_archive];

IF (@lastrun < CAST(GETDATE() as date))
BEGIN
    /* delete data from one year ago */
    DELETE FROM [cadc].[dbo].[inventory_archive] WHERE entry_date = CAST((DATEADD(yy, -1, GetDate())) as DATE);

    /* insert todays inventory */
    INSERT INTO [cadc].[dbo].[inventory_archive] (sku, tag_id , load_id, batch, status, qc_status, location, eaches, units, cartons, r_date, e_date, zone_1, zone_2, loc_type, loc_pick, mod_time, receiver_no, mfg_code, each_unit, unit_carton)
        SELECT sku, tag_id , load_id, batch, status, qc_status, location, eaches, units, cartons, r_date, e_date, zone_1, zone_2, loc_type, loc_pick, mod_time, receiver_no, mfg_code, each_unit, unit_carton 
        FROM [cadc].[dbo].[inventory];
END
END
```

As pointed out above by @marc_s I am going to try and move this to a job that runs.

Comment: I'd move `USE cadc` to the beginning of the script. Otherwise if the trigger already exists but you start the script in a different database, it will fail to execute the CREATE TRIGGER statement.